# MySQL Server 5.7 and WAMPServer in the same machine wamp can't run

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have installed mysqlserver 5.7 and after that I can not run wampserver it's orange icon never turn to green. any body please help.

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry One correction its  mysqlServer 5.7 and there is no error just the icon is orange  and never turn green and I found it's works fine  but icon is still orage  both mysqlserver  and wamp mysql usieng 3306 port.

Comment: Is it mysql or SQLserver, because those are two different piece of software. You shouldn't mix them like that while you talk, or it might cause some confusion.

Comment: I am 99% certain you're talking about [tag:mysql] rather than [tag:sql-server]. SQL Server version *8* had the marketing name "2000" and all of the version numbers and years have moved up since then. I don't think there ever was a version 5.7 for SQL Server. (In fact, [version 6 was release in 1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#History))

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever See comment 2 where he makes that correction

Comment: Then the OP, or you in your edits, should at the least, *correct the tags*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ok, done. I didnt spot the tag believe it or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAMPServer also has a MySQL Server installed as part of it.

By default MySQL Server talks with the outside world using a TCP port (3306) and only one app can be using a TCP port at any one time.

So basically you have 2 people both trying to use the same phone line, which is not possible.

If you have WAMPServer installed you have no need to install another MySQL Server instance, so I suggest you uninstall the independant MySQ Server that you have installed. It is quite possible for one MySQL Server to run 100's of seperate databases, so if you thought you needed ONE MYSQL PER DATABASE that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the configurations and make them run on different ports. For me I installed MySQL server 5.7 first and after I tried to install wamp, but it couldn't run. Go to C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17 and edit the following lines in the file **my.ini**

```
[client]
#password= your_password
port= 3308

[wampmysqld]
port= 3308

[mysqld]
port=3308
```

I also edited the file:**mysql_config.pl** in C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin

```
 $port = '3308';
```

save changes and restart WAMP, it should launch normally.